# outputLables rendered with AJAX not getting retained when validation fails in JSF Primefaces

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, rendering, retain

We are working on a banking application where we are using JSF, Primefaces as the main technologies. While developing a page, we faced an issue related to Page Validation. The functionality is for doing a financial transaction. On click of account no in 'From Account' dropdown, it fetches balance of the account using AJAX and shows the user on the screen. After selecting 'From Account', if we submit the screen it retains the value in the drop-down but the balance field which was derived using AJAX is cleared. My requirement is to retain that field as well and on change of the dropdown, change the value accordingly. The code is given below.

test1.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>:: Test1 ::</title>
    <script>
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/template.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="mainForm">
<div align="center">
<p:panel id="txnPanel" header="Accont Transfer" style="width: 70%; text-align:left;" >
    <p:fieldset>
        <p:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="gridlessTable" style="width:100%;margin:0px auto;" columnClasses="headerColumn,separatorColumn,dataColumn,errorColumn">
            <p:outputLabel for="fromAccount" value="From Account" styleClass="lables" />
            <p:outputLabel value=":" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="fromAccount" value="#{testView.fromAccount}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Select From Account">
                <p:ajax listener="#{testView.getFromAccountDetails()}" update="availableBalance" event="change"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="----- Select Account -----" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{test1View.accountList}" var="account" itemLabel="#{account}" itemValue="#{account}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:message for="fromAccount" styleClass="error"/>

            <p:outputLabel for="availableBalance" value="Available Balance" styleClass="lables"/>
            <p:outputLabel value=":" />
            <p:outputLabel id="availableBalance" value="#{testView.fromAccountBalance}"/>
            <p:spacer />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:fieldset>
    <p:fieldset>
        <p:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="gridlessTable" style="width:100%;margin:0px auto;" columnClasses="headerColumn,separatorColumn,dataColumn,errorColumn">
            <p:outputLabel for="toAccount" value="To Account" styleClass="lables" />
            <p:outputLabel value=":" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="toAccount" value="#{testView.toAccount}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Select To Account">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="----- Select Account -----" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{test1View.accountList}" var="account" itemLabel="#{account}" itemValue="#{account}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:message for="toAccount" styleClass="error" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:fieldset>
    <p:fieldset>
        <p:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="gridlessTable" style="width:100%;margin:0px auto;" columnClasses="headerColumn,separatorColumn,dataColumn,errorColumn">
            <p:outputLabel for="txnAmount" value="Amount" styleClass="lables"  required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Amount"/>
            <p:outputLabel value=":" />
            <p:inputText id="txnAmount" value="#{testView.txnAmount}" size="20" maxlength="50" styleClass="amountInput"/>
            <p:message for="txnAmount" styleClass="error" />

            <p:outputLabel for="narration" value="Narration" styleClass="lables"  required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Narration"/>
            <p:outputLabel value=":" />
            <p:inputText id="narration" value="#{testView.narration}" size="35" maxlength="50"/>
            <p:message for="narration" styleClass="error" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:fieldset>

    <div align="center">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">
            <p:commandButton value="Submit"
                type="submit"
                action="#{testView.doTransaction()}" validateClient="true" id="submitButton" ajax="false" update="txnPanel">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </div>
</p:panel>
</div>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Test1View.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test1View{

    private ArrayList<String> accountList = null;

    public Test1View(){
        accountList = new ArrayList<String>();
        accountList.add("ABC");
        accountList.add("DEF");
        accountList.add("GHI");
        accountList.add("JKL");
        accountList.add("MNO");
        accountList.add("PQR");
        accountList.add("STU");
        accountList.add("VWX");
        accountList.add("YZA");
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAccountList() {
        return accountList;
    }

    public void setAccountList(ArrayList<String> accountList) {
        this.accountList = accountList;
    }

}
```

TestView.java

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class TestView{

    private String fromAccount;
    private String toAccount;
    private String narration;
    private BigDecimal txnAmount;
    private BigDecimal fromAccountBalance;

    public BigDecimal getFromAccountBalance() {
        return fromAccountBalance;
    }

    public void setFromAccountBalance(BigDecimal fromAccountBalance) {
        this.fromAccountBalance = fromAccountBalance;
    }

    public String getFromAccount() {
        return fromAccount;
    }

    public void setFromAccount(String fromAccount) {
        this.fromAccount = fromAccount;
    }

    public String getToAccount() {
        return toAccount;
    }

    public void setToAccount(String toAccount) {
        this.toAccount = toAccount;
    }

    public String getNarration() {
        return narration;
    }

    public void setNarration(String narration) {
        this.narration = narration;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTxnAmount() {
        return txnAmount;
    }

    public void setTxnAmount(BigDecimal txnAmount) {
        this.txnAmount = txnAmount;
    }

    public void getFromAccountDetails() {
        if(fromAccount != null && !fromAccount.equals("")){
            fromAccountBalance = new BigDecimal(Math.random() * 4867.0);
        }
        else{
            fromAccountBalance = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Do own account transaction.
     * 
     * @return the string
     */
    public String doTransaction(){
        String returnValue = null;

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

template.css

```
.ui-widget-content.ui-datatable-even {
    background: #FFFFFF; !important;
}

.ui-outputlabel.ui-widget.lables {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

.amountRed {
    color: #b70808 !important;
}

.amountInput {
    text-align: right !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}

.gridlessTable tr, .gridlessTable td {
    border: none !important;
}

.ui-inputtext {
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
.headerColumn{
    width: 24% !important;
    height:25px !important;
    text-align: left;
}
.separatorColumn{
    width: 1% !important;
    height:auto !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}
.dataColumn{
    width: 40% !important;
    height:25px !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}
.errorColumn{
    width: 30% !important;
    height:auto !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

Screenshots are attached here.

[image: After the page is loaded]
[image: After the account is selected]
[image: After submitted with only From Account Selected]
01. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI6OA.jpg
02. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k33h.jpg
03. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qguni.jpg

Comment: You happened to post back to the same view using `ajax="false"` in `<p:commandButton>` (implication : returning `null` from the action method `doTransaction()`). Thus you should also end up with a duplicate form submission. Since it is a bank application, a duplicate form submission, in this case, should not be compromised. Is setting the `ajax` attribute of the given `<p:commandButton>` to `false` absolutely necessary for some unclear reason(s)?

Comment: The doTransaction() method is going to do the processing, however my current issue is coming even before the doTransaction() is executed. I tried doing ajax="true" but well, it didn't even give me the validation messages.